# Calling Python constructor with default arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments

Suppose you have a Python class whose constructor looks something like this:

```
 def __init__(self,fname=None,data=[],imobj=None,height=0,width=0):
```

and you want to create an instance of it but only provide the fname and imobj inputs. Would the correct way to do this be

```
thing = Thing(f_name, None, im_obj, None, None)
```

or is there a preferred way of making this call?

Comment: Just use named arguments:  "Thing(fname=f_name, imobj=im_obj)", everything else defaults.

Comment: You don't want that `data=[]` as a default argument, as iCodez writes below. What you want is `data=None`, then in the body of the `__init__` you can write `if data is None: self.data = []` or whatever you had planned to do with it.

Answer (score 6):

You can just do:

```
thing = Thing(f_name=value1, im_obj=value2)
```

Note that you do not actually *need* the `f_name=` in this case since `fname` is the first parameter (besides `self`, which is passed implicitly).  You could just do:

```
thing = Thing(value1, im_obj=value2)
```

But I personally think that the first solution is more readable.  It makes it clear that we are only changing the values of `f_name` and `im_obj` while leaving every other parameter to its default value.  In addition, it keeps people from wondering what parameter `value1` will be assigned to.

Also, you almost never want to have a mutable object such as a list be a default argument.  It will be shared across all calls of the function.  For more information, see ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument?rq=1)

Comment: *you should never have a mutable object such as a list as a default argument* - not necessarily **never** - but 99% of the time, it's definitely not what you want and is going to bite you.

Comment: There, I used "almost never". :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can instanciate with:

```
thing = Thing(f_name, imobj=im_obj)
```

Other named arguments will be set to default.

You can also pass a dict to the constructor:

```
>>> argDict={"fname": f_name, "imobj": im_obj}
>>> thing = Thing(**argDict)
```

This will unpack the dict values. See [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).